# Spring MVC Async task runs synchronously

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, asynchronous

I'd like to implement an asynchronous task, and a page which returns immediately and starts the task in the background. However, the page instead waits for the background task to complete and returns only afterwards. When I visit `/start` it takes 15s to load the page. I'm using Spring 3.2.0. I have a line containing `<task:annotation-driven/>` in my test-servlet.xml.

The odd thing is that even if I replace @Async with @Async("this_bean_does_not_exist"), the application does the same(though I would be expecting an exception for referencing a not existing bean).

```
public interface AsyncTestService {
    void startSlowProcess();
}
```

---

```
@Service
public class AsyncTestServiceImpl implements AsyncTestService {

    @Override
    @Async
    public void startSlowProcess() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(15000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
@Controller
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    AsyncTestService asyncTestService;

    @RequestMapping("/start")
    @ResponseBody
    public String startSlowProcess() {
        asyncTestService.startSlowProcess(); // It takes 15s to complete
        return "STARTED"; // should return immediately
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need an [executor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/scheduling.html). Try this:

```
<task:annotation-driven executor="myExecutor" />    
<task:executor id="myExecutor" pool-size="5"/>
```

**EDIT:** Another possible solution: use [EnableAsync](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/EnableAsync.html) instead (available since Spring 3.1)

Comment: Have you cleaned your project before testing? Could you verify, if the executor is actually running? According to the docs (see link above), an explicitly declared executor instance is required for this to work.

Comment: Yes! I was missing EnableAsync from my config. Thank you!

Comment: Yup, the `@EnableAsync` worked. AND transactional stuff seems to work fine with DAO's. But I can shake the fear that there are hidden pitfalls here when combined with Web and Rest etc (?)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly make your `.xml` config looks like:

```
<task:scheduler id="myScheduler" pool-size="10" />
<task:executor id="myExecutor" pool-size="10" />
<task:annotation-driven executor="myExecutor" scheduler="myScheduler" proxy-target-class="true" />
```

(Yes, scheduler count and executor thread pool size is configurable)

Or just use default:

```
<!-- enable task annotation to support @Async, @Scheduled, ... -->
<task:annotation-driven />
```

Secondly make sure `@Async` methods are public.